# STL Push_back string in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to push a string in a string vector,  like below

```
void Node::set_val(string &val)
{
    this->val.push_back(val);
}
```

But when I try to call it as below

```
Obj.set_val("10h;");
```

I get the below error,

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Node::set_val(const char [5])'
```

I assumed that the string in " " is same as `string` in c++, Why do I get such an error? What has to be changed below?

Comment: Your `set_val` expects a reference to `std::string` as parameter. But you are only passing a const array of 5 characters.

Comment: @MertMertce that was just for explanation, I am calling it via object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are taking in a `std::string` by non-const reference. Non-const references cannot bind to rvalues, like `"10h;"`, so you can't pass literals in to that function.

If you aren't going to modify the argument, you should take your argument by reference-to-const:

```
void Node::set_val(const string &val)
//                 ^^^^^
```

This way, a temporary `std::string` will be constructed from your `const char[5]` and passed in to `set_val`.

You could improve this by taking in the `string` by value and `move`ing it into the `vector`:

```
void Node::set_val(string val)
{
    this->val.push_back(std::move(val));
}
```

This prevents you from making some unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 2):

So in C++, const char* is implicitly convertible to std::string because std::string has a (non-explicit) constructor that takes const char*. So what the compiler tries here is to create a temporary std::string object for your function call, like so:

```
Node.set_val(std::string("10h;"));
```

However, since you declared the parameter of set_val to be a non-const reference to a std::string, the compiler can't make this conversion work due to the fact that temporary objects can't be bound to non-const references.

There are three ways to make this work, depending on what you want to achieve:

```
void Node::set_val(const std::string& val) {}
void Node::set_val(std::string val) {}
void Node::set_val(std::string&& val) {}
```

All will compile (the last one requires C++11 or higher), but seeing your use case, I would recommend to use the second or third one. For an explanation why, try reading a little bit about move semantics in C++11.

The important thing to take away here is that const char* implicitly converts to std::string by creating a temporary object, and temporary objects can't be passed to functions taking non-const references.

Comment: I would not recommend using the third option as you can't pass lvalues in to it.

Comment: Of course you are right. I just find that the third option makes it clearer that this is a sink function. Granted, this was just my assumption that it was a sink function, so the second case is actually the more flexible one. But thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `"10h;"` which is a const char array.

Fix it by passing a string: `Obj.set_val(string("10h"));` and edit function to take a string by value:

```
void Node::set_val(string val) { /* */ }
```

Or maybe better, edit your function to take a `const string&`:

```
void Node::set_val(const string &val) { /* */ }
```